# Creating ribbon menus with tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Is there a way to create menu's such as the one provided in [WordPad](http://res2.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows%207/main/e01a8958-bba5-49f4-9fe1-f6810db16ba0_0.jpg) on Windows 7 with Tkinter?
I haven't found anything like it, and it would improve the looks on my scripts immensely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is what Microsoft calls a [ribbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_(computing)). No, there is nothing built-in to tkinter to provide such a menu. Most of the building blocks are there to emulate it (notebooks, buttons, dropdowns, etc), but you'll have to do a fair amount of work to get it to work exactly like a ribbon.

The consensus on ribbons seem to be that they only aid usability when you have a very large amount of controls that you need to present to the user. That is why you see such ribbons on tools like Word and Excel, but not so much on browsers, notepad, etc. I would advise that unless your app *needs* such a rich toolbar, adding one won't actually improve the usability of your application.